# Too wide subfigures

Tags: floatrow

I try to place to figures side by side, as can be seen below the resulting figures are to wide, they expand over the right document border. Do I have to take the gap into account when sizing the images, and if so how do I do it, so that I don"t have to adjust if I globally change the gap size?

[image: overset image]

MWE: (Fancyhdr is used to show tha actual width of the main text area)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}                            %we base the subfigures on this
\usepackage[list=on]{subcaption}                %we base the subfigures on this
\usepackage{floatrow}                           %subfigures
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}                          %limit graphics sizes

%floatrow setup
\floatsetup{style=ruled,footposition=caption,capposition=bottom, heightadjust=object}   %make graphics look like booktables
\floatsetup[table]{style=plain,footposition=bottom}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{style= plain, heightadjust=object, valign=t}
\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=brace,justification=centerlast}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.0pt}

\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\fps@figure{!htb}
\setlength\@fptop{0pt} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{
    \begin{subfloatrow}
        \ffigbox[.5\Xhsize]{\caption{cap1}}{\includegraphics[width=.5\Xhsize]{}}
        \ffigbox[\Xhsize]{\caption{cap2}}{\includegraphics[width=\Xhsize, height=5cm]{}}
    \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{Tile network}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @dustin: In the end this will end up in a template were I won't pick the margins, besides wouldn't the original issue reamin that the 2 figures side by side extend slightly further than the text?

Comment: `\Xhsize` comes from the floatrow package. It tells you how much you have left on that floatrow. In the beginning I take half the width since I have the entire row. After placing the first picture I have used half the page therefore \Xhsize is now '\linewidth'-half a page = half a page.

Comment: Try `.5\linewidth` as you will see the renders will become to small. (Must be with the `floatrow` enviornment I think it uses minipages internallz or something). `\XHsize` is what the `floatrow` package offers if you want to fill a line.

Comment: So I have a tried adjusting the geometry and making the figures small, but it will still do that no matter what the size of the figures or margins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have fixed the with of `\includegraphics` exactly as big as `\ffigbox`. Probably the problem is only that the content can not be as big as the container.

Narrowing a pinch the images, for example to `.45\Xhsize` and `.95\Xhsize`, seem to solve the problem and it is even more elegant (IMHO, of course). With `.499\Xhsize` and `.999 \Xhsize` the horizontal difference between rules and image margins is almost imperceptible even zooming at 400%.

> [image: MWE]

Comment: Fair enough, but I am slightly disappointed considering that it works perfectly without `subfloatrow`...