# Apply floatrow style to align and glossary

Tags: floats, floatrow

I use the `booktabs` package and the `floatrow` package with the float style `ruled`. For consistency I would like to apply this [look (example)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125686/19326) to the glossary I use as nomenclature and an `amsmath` enviornment. So far I use the `caption` technic described in the `floatrow` manual, using `captionsetup` and `caption`.

I wonder if there is any easy way to trick `floatrow` into handling a minipage like a float and adding the appropiate rules.

Here is a not so minimal example. It includes a `table` and a `figure` that look like I want them too. And a not correctly formated `glossary` and `align` environment.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=on]{subcaption}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\floatsetup{style=ruled, footposition=caption, capposition=bottom, heightadjust=object}   %make graphics look like booktables
\floatsetup[table]{style=plain, footposition=bottom}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}

\newglossaryentry{demo}{
                    name        =modulo,
                    symbol      =\ensuremath{\protect \bmod},
                    description ={modulo operator}}

\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\chapter{needs work}
\begin{center}%vertical spacing
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%group caption and content on same page
    \centering
    \captionsetup{type=table}
    \begin{align}
        1+2=3
    \end{align}
    \caption{Align}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{center}%vertical spacing
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%group caption and content on same page
    \centering
    \captionsetup{type=table}
    \renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
    \printglossary
    \caption{Nomenclature glossary}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\chapter{should be look}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lrrp{5cm}}
    \toprule
    %name & lines per set & sets & pros/cons\\
     & hea &der \\
    \midrule
    con & ten & t \\
    con & ten & t \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=2in, width=4in]{}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your table in chapter 2 "should be look" has no rules, so I assume you don't want table captions to have rules. That's exactly what happens to your align and glossary captions since you declared them of type `table`. What is the problem then? Am I missing something?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: yes. I tried `    \captionsetup{type=table, style=ruled}` (inside the minipages where I set the anchor) but this does not have effect. I marked them as tables, since that is the `list of x` I want them to appear in.

Comment: Additional note: I want those to items to be wrapped like `figure` (line above top and arround caption), I just turned it off for tables since it looks bad with booktabs.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Please see my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a `figure` environment, but with the `H` placement specifier and `\captionsetup{type=table}`; in this way, the objects will receive the desired `ruled` style, won't float (`H` means "exactly here") and will have their captions as table captions:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=on]{subcaption}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\makeglossaries

\DeclareFloatVCode{rule}{\vskip2pt\hrule\vskip4pt}
\DeclareFloatVCode{lowrule}{\par\rule{\hsize}{.8pt}\par}

\floatsetup{style=ruled, footposition=caption, capposition=bottom, heightadjust=object}   %make graphics look like booktables
\floatsetup[table]{style=plain, footposition=bottom}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}

\newglossaryentry{demo}{
  name=modulo,
  symbol=\ensuremath{\protect \bmod},
  description={modulo operator}}
\newglossaryentry{permutation}{
  name=\ensuremath{(12)},
  description={a permutation}}

\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\chapter{A solution}
\gls{demo}, \gls{permutation}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{type=table}
    \begin{align}
        1+2=3
    \end{align}
    \caption{Align}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{type=table}
    \renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
    \printglossary
    \caption{Nomenclature glossary}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also changed the definitions of `rule` and `lowrule` used for the `ruled` style so that the initial and final rules are thicker than the middle line separating the object and its caption, and providing a better vertical spacing between the rules and the caption.

Comment: now I see my mistake, I tried this with `[h!]` and latex told me that it changed it to `[ht!]` which was unacceptable for me, since I do not want the nomenclature float infront of the section heading that reads `nomenclature`.

Comment: the table headers look much nicer using booktabs (i checked the manual to make sure) -- the text should be vertically centered, or nearly so.  so i'm not sure what's happeneng here.  perhaps putting the caption at the bottom?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've made some adjustments to the rules ans the spacing bettwen the rules and the caption in the default ruled style. Hope it's better now.

Comment: @ted I updated my answer introducing some modifications to the rules and the spacing.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- oh, very much nicer!  thanks.  (i like to see answers that set good examples.)

Comment: Your adjustment is nice, it made everything look better. It should become a patch for floatrow if the options `style=ruled` and `capposition=bottom` are applied together.