# fitting side by side figures with floatrow

Tags: floats, floatrow

I'm trying to fit two figures side by side (with the same size) in the width of the text, using the `floatrow` package. I use the `showframe` option and the `\fbox` in mwe for better visualization. how to fit perfectly on text width?

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow} 

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\ffigbox[\textwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}[2]\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{0.75pt}\fbox{\ffigbox[0.49\textwidth]
{
    \caption{sidewalk perforation}
    \label{subfig:furadeira}
}
{   \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \setlength\fboxrule{0.75pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{image1.jpg}}}
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \setlength\fboxrule{0.75pt}}
    \fbox{\ffigbox[0.49\textwidth]
{
\caption{volatile organic compounds measurement}
\label{subfig:medicaomalha}
}
{
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \setlength\fboxrule{0.75pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{image2.jpg}}
}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}
{
    \caption{Hot spot investigation}
    \label{fig:hotspot}
}
\end{figure}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too wide subfigures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125686/too-wide-subfigures)?

Comment: "You have fixed the with of \includegraphics exactly as big as \ffigbox." but in my case, the \includegraphics is already smaller than \ffigbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the default floatseparator (`\columnsep`) used. None of the predefined separators will be of use here given the widths of your figures, but you can easily define one using `\DeclareFloatSeparators`:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow} 

\DeclareFloatSeparators{myfill}{\hskip.013\textwidth plus1fill}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\floatsetup[subfloat]{floatrowsep=myfill}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{0.75pt}
\ffigbox[\textwidth]
{
\begin{subfloatrow}[2]
%\fbox{
\ffigbox[.49\textwidth]
  {
    \caption{sidewalk perforation}
    \label{subfig:furadeira}
  }
  {
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
  }
%}
%\fbox{
\ffigbox[.49\textwidth]
  {
    \caption{volatile organic compounds measurement}
    \label{subfig:medicaomalha}
  }
  {
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
  }
%}
\end{subfloatrow}%
}
{
    \caption{Hot spot investigation}
    \label{fig:hotspot}
}
\end{figure}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that there's still some spurious blank space to the left of the first subfligure; I suspect this is a bug in `floatrow.sty` (most probably a missing `%` to kill a surious space).

To have the subfigures perfectly flushed to the margins, I'd suggest you a work-around using floatrow instead of subfloatrow and using \captionof{subfigure}{text...} to provide the captions:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow} 

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\ffigbox[\textwidth]
  {
    \begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox[\linewidth]
      {\captionof{subfigure}{sidewalk perforation}
      \label{subfig:furadeira}}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \ffigbox[\linewidth]
      {\captionof{subfigure}{volatile organic compounds measurement}
      \label{subfig:medicaomalha}}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{floatrow}%
  }
  {\caption{Hot spot investigation}\label{fig:hotspot}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the second solution works perfectly!!! thanks!!

Comment: i tryed to use \DeclareFloatSeparators{myfill}{\hfill}  \floatsetup[subfigure]{subfloatrowsep=myfill} but it didnt work. I agree with you: may be there is a bug in floatrow.

Comment: i've found a error!!i'm using \usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Fig. \thefigure.\arabic{subfigure}}. in preamble and the captionof show a wrong numbering. in the case of this mwe: (Fig. 0.1) and (Fig. 0.2)

Comment: @user42634 well, that's the expected result with your settings. You are prepending the `figure` counter to subfigures, but place captions for subfigures *before* the caption for the figure, so the *figure* counter has not yet stepped and the wrong number is picked. Why do you need the counter of the figure for the subfigures?

Comment: @user42634 If the captions for subfigures will *always* be before the caption for the figure, with your current settings you'll need to step the counter as in `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Fig. \number\numexpr\thefigure+1\relax.\arabic{subfigure}}`.