# Get the value of custom (pseudo?) length

Tags: lengths

I defined a [custom length for horizontal separation of subfloats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164339/28685) through

```
\DeclareFloatSeparators{halfgap}{\hskip0.5\columnsep}
```

and use it on a float by float basis with

```
\thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=halfgap}
```

but I also need to use such length in a `\fpeval` calculation, is it possible?

Comment: Sorry to have misled you! I comment instead of answer when I haven't tested the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might say

```
\newcommand{\halfgap}{0.5\columnsep}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{halfgap}{\hspace{\halfgap}}
```

Then you can use `\halfgap` wherever you need to refer to the length.

Don't follow the suggestion to say

```
\newlength{\halfgap}
\setlength{\halfgap}{0.5\columnsep}
```

because this would fix the value as it is computed when processing the document preamble, whereas `\columnsep` might change later.